# change font size of axisLabel

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

How to increase the font size of only the axisLabels and not tick labels.
[image]

As you can see the axislabel font size is too small. if i give styling to text, all the text in chart is changed. I just want to change axislabel i.e Priority and Number of Alerts in this case to change. Is there a way to access only axisLabels?

Comment: Have you tried selecting them by class or some other axis identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example : http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/juY5E/336/

I have appended a button that when clicked changes the font colour and the font size.

First off, when creating the text, I give it an ID (line 116) :

```
  svg.append("text")
    .attr('id','xAxisText')
```

Then I created a function that gets called when you click the button :

```
function changeFontColour(){
         d3.select('#xAxisText').style('fill','red').style('font-size', 30)
        }
```

This selects the text, then fills it red, then changes the font size to 30 :)